# loading issue of subpackages in astropy 0.3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, astropy

I have successfully install astropy-0.3 with python-3.4 on Ubuntu-14.04 but whenever I search any conventional library of Astropy like cosmology, time, units it doesn't work here.. Is this library specifically made for windows or any thing else?

I am using Astropy library on IDLE python-2.7 conveniently.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you describe in what sense you cannot "search any conventional library"? Perhaps include the code you want to execute and the error it gives.

Comment: simply **dir (astropy)** doesn't give me any of the above library (I can't access to astropy.cosmology, astropy.units, astropy.time) While in windows I can..

Comment: and "import astropy.cosmology"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-astropy
```

Now to check if it is working open IDLE3 and run the following commands in IDLE3:

```
import astropy
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
dir(astropy)
```

The expected output of `dir(astropy)` is:

```
['ConfigurationItem', 'UNICODE_OUTPUT', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__githash__', '__loader__', '__minimum_numpy_version__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_check_numpy', '_get_test_runner', '_init_log', '_initialize_astropy', '_teardown_log', 'config', 'constants', 'coordinates', 'cosmology', 'cython_version', 'extern', 'find_api_page', 'io', 'log', 'logger', 'logging', 'online_docs_root', 'table', 'test', 'time', 'units', 'utils', 'version', 'version_helpers', 'wcs']
```

The above output shows that the built-in functions of astropy that you mentioned in your question: cosmology, time and units have all been successfully imported.

The following Python code<sup>**1**</sup> is a simple test to check if the cosmology and units built-in functions of astropy are working correctly. From IDLE3 run the following commands:

```
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
H0 = cosmo.H(0)
H0.value, H0.unit
```

The expected output is:

```
(69.32, Unit("km / (Mpc s)"))
```

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Source: [Cosmological Calculations (astropy.cosmology)](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cosmology/)</sub>

Comment: See also [my response](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/astropy/2014-August/003347.html) from just the other day on the AstroPy mailing list to a user who was confused about how submodules work in Python.